# AJAX File Upload to LotusScript Agent

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

Im trying to upload a file using a LotusScript agent for the backend - I have a simple form with an upload control on it and am using AJAX to submit the form (using YUI Connection Manager) to the LotusScript Agent (POST).

In the LotusScript agent I am getting the request_content field - but am unable to translate that into a file.

Has anyone done this ? This is the output the request_content field shows at the moment

```
-----------------------------25102100326869 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="__Click"  0 -----------------------------25102100326869 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileUpload"; filename="vannes map.JPG" Content-Type: image/jpeg   Ï Ó IF ·· ` `   ¦ C ec  ·· $.' ",#(7),01444'9=82<.342 ¦ C·  2!!222222222222222222222222222222
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be far, far easier to submit to a Form that has an upload control on it and uses a WebQuerySave agent to move the attachment it creates and set the SaveOptions to "0" to prevent the document save.

Comment: It would be - yes I agree ... however I want an AJAX upload without refreshing the page. I am looking at the hidden iFrame and doing the WDQ method in that ...

Comment: You can do an Ajax POST to a Form design element just as easily as you can to an Agent. The URL QueryString would start with ?CreateDocument -- the form doesn't need to be loaded into the browser, and you don't need to worry about the sequence number if you use ?CreateDocument instead of ?OpenForm.